# Autologin Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

Trying to autologin a user,  on `Auth::user()` it returns `null`. I have two services,  from Service 1 I send logged-in user data to Service 2 with rabbitmq and on the job handle, I wanna check if that user doesn't exist on Service 2 then register and autologin, if it exists autologin. I am having 1 issue

1. On `Auth::user()` returns `null` even after authentication

Service 2 handle method:

```
 public function handle()
    {
        $user_email =  $this->data['email'];
        $user_exist = DB::table('users')->where('email',$user_email)->first();
        if($user_exist === null){
            $user = User::create([
                        'name' => $this->data['name'],
                        'email' => $this->data['email'],
                        'password' => bcrypt('password'),
                    ]);
            Auth::loginUsingId($user->id);
            //Auth::login($user); // I tried this method instead of  Auth::loginUsingId still same result
            dd(Auth::check()); // returns true;
        }else{
            Auth::loginUsingId($user_exist->id);
        }
    }
```

Comment: where `Auth::user()` is null? are you using custom auth guard?

Comment: No I am not using custom auth guard , and is null on service 2 controller in my case in ChatController

Comment: please share the route and let me know if it is working with existing user or not

Comment: PHP died after each request - user authenticated only on rabbit job runtime. Populate question with your use case for this logic.\

Comment: How can I save the user from handle method and use it on a controller?